# How to select image from sqlite database and append it to imageview?

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, byte

```
Byte[] image_byte = new Byte[];


while(rs.next()){
    image_byte = rs.getBytes("Image");
    // What do I write here ?
}
```

I can take Bytes from sqlite, but I can not go on. What shold I write next ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe you can take BufferedArrayInputStream to cremte your Image as shown [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2175375?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Thanks, I have resourced that and found a solution like yours :)